AddNew function - If linked to SQL back end i get Run time error "3219" invalid operation
I have very old access database that i have inherited.
It was converted from access backend tables to sql back end tables many years ago, again, inherited work.
The users report that when they want to add a new record to a list, the get a run time error "3219" invalid operation.
When i test it, i see that this only happens when the backend table is linked to SQL.  If i have the same database with local tables it adds the new record without issue.
This is the code and where it falls over.
I am expecting it to add a name to a table called People
Private Sub Driver_ID_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)
Dim ctl As Control
Dim PeopleRecs, PeopStat
Dim FirstName, LastName As String
Dim Tmp_Space As Integer

    ' Return Control object that points to combo box.
    Set ctl = Me![Driver ID]
    ' Prompt user to verify they wish to add new value.
    If MsgBox("'" & NewData & "' is not in the list. Do you want to Add it?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
        ' Set Response argument to indicate that data is being added.
        Response = acDataErrAdded
        ' Add string in NewData argument to row source.
        Tmp_Space = InStr(1, NewData, " ")
        If Tmp_Space > 0 Then
            FirstName = Left(NewData, Tmp_Space - 1)
            LastName = Mid(NewData, Tmp_Space + 1, Len(NewData) - Tmp_Space)
        Else
            FirstName = ""
            LastName = NewData
        End If
        sqlstr = "SELECT [Person ID],[First name],[Last Name] from [People]"
        Set PeopleRecs = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(sqlstr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        sqlstr = "SELECT [Person ID],[Status] FROM [People Status]"
        Set PeopStat = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(sqlstr, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
        With PeopleRecs
            .AddNew
            ![Person ID] = NextID("Person")
            ![First Name] = FirstName
            ![Last Name] = LastName
           ** PeopStat.AddNew**
            PeopStat.[Person ID] = PeopleRecs.[Person ID]
            PeopStat.[Status] = "Car Driver"
            .Update
            .Close
            PeopStat.Update
            PeopStat.Close
        End With
    Else
    ' If user chooses Cancel, suppress error message and undo changes.
        Response = acDataErrContinue
        ctl.Undo
    End If

End Sub


"this only happens when the backend table is linked to SQL" check for an insert trigger on the SQL table. Also, try to manually add a record to the SQL table via a tool like SSMS.

It probably doesn't like the mixed inserts. Try:
Dim NewID As Long
NewID = NextID("Person")

With PeopleRecs
    .AddNew
    ![Person ID] = NewID
    ![First Name] = FirstName
    ![Last Name] = LastName
    .Update
    .Close
End With
With PeopStat
    .AddNew
    ![Person ID] = NewID
    ![Status] = "Car Driver"
    .Update
    .Close
End With


Also note how much easier this is to read, understand and debug. @KateM
